# How can I transfer Ubuntu from a stick to a new SSD

Tags: installation, ssd

My SSD died a month ago, I ordered a new SSD that has just arrived.

In the meantime I had installed (with friendly help) and had been running Ubuntu from a USB stick.

Now I'd like to transfer Ubuntu from the USB stick on to the new installed SSD.

What should I do?

At the moment the SSD is not mounted and is formatted as FAT 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dd to clone the USB stick to SSD.

dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy

Where sdx is the drive you wish to clone from and sdy is the drive you wish to clone to.

This can be dangerous if you are not expert with dd, Google before proceeding.

What are you using on the USB, a Full install or a Persistent install?

A Persistent install has limitations when used as a main o/s, such as inability to upgrade and update. You would also need to make an ext4 casper-rw partition to get more than 4GB of persistence.

If you are using a Full install you can expand partition size after cloning.

If you do not wish to use dd, you can copy using rsync, grsync is a gui version.