# Transfer Ubuntu from USB to new SSD

Tags: 14.04, usb, ssd

This question follows on from my [previous one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613246/ubuntu-desktop-newbie/613249#613249).  I have decided to take the plunge and replace my faulty hard disk with a brand new SSD drive.  In the mean time I have done a fair bit of customization with my current USB installation.  Here is what I have done

1. Booted up from the LiveCD version of Ubuntu
2. Done a full Ubuntu install to my 32Gb USB stick
3. Done a lengthy apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.
4. Installed Opera,HostSSH,JEdit + customizations...

I have little deisre to go through all of that all over again for the new SSD.  Is there any proven way to just transfer the working USB installation over to the new SSD drive?  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357232/how-can-i-transfer-ubuntu-from-a-stick-to-a-new-ssd) has a possible answer but given that it was not accepted I have no way of knowing whether it works. I'd much appreciate any help.

The SSD I will be installing is a 120Gb SanDisk SSD Plus

SanDisk SDSSDA-120G-G25 Plus

Comment: Provide the model and manufacturer of your SSD so that it will be possible to determine whether TRIM support is enabled out of the box or whether you need to enable it manually.

Comment: You can try [this way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524418/how-would-i-use-tar-for-full-backup-and-restore-with-system-on-ssd-and-home-on-h). You'll, obviously need to fix fstab, and reinstall Grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A got it working by dd, even though I don't know, if data is written the same. So, if /dev/sda is your ssd and /dev/sdb is your USB key, you can do a simple dd, just like:
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda

You have to make correction with gparted (from a CD/DVD) to make it working correctly and expand the given space. I made it on several machines. I remember only two times I did it (one was just a broken partition, the other was an entire disk).

Comment: make correction with gparted... Could you elaborate?

Comment: By the dd command you'll create a disk that has the size of a USB stick. I presume you want to use all 120GBs :) That's where gparted comes in. By using gparted you can extend the disk to 120GBs.